# ¿Por qué el segundo loop de esta lista es el numero 8?

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Este es el codigo:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(2):
  a[i] = a[i] + a[i-1]

print(a)

#output: [6, 8]
```

lo que yo entiendo es esto:

## primer loop

```
#primer paso

a[0] = a[0] + a[0-1]

#segundo paso

a[0] = 1 + 5

#ultimo paso

[0] = 6
```

## segundo loop

```
#primer paso

a[1] = a[1] + a[1-1]

#segundo paso

a[1] = 2 + 1

#ultimo paso

a[1] = 3
```

segun mi razonamiento la respuesta es [6,3].
¿En donde esta mi error? Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

te explico tu error de razonanamiento.

**Primer loop, bien razonado.**

primer paso

```
a[0] = a[0] + a[0-1]
```

segundo paso

```
a[0] = 1 + 5
```

ultimo paso

```
[0] = 6
```

**segundo loop**

primer paso

```
a[1] = a[1] + a[1-1]
```

segundo paso

```
a[1] = 2 + 1 //Aqui esta tu error lo correcto seria = a[1] = 2 + 6 (Que es a lo que corresponde a[1-1]  =  a[0] = 6) .
```

ultimo paso **corregido**.

```
a[1] = **8**
```

Saludos.